# Sending Document and Text both in WhatsApp

Tags: android, whatsapp

Currently, I wanted to send app generated PDF or Excel file from WhatsApp with text. But after opening chat screen only file getting sends and not a text.
Same code working for email client where text gets added as a body

```
Intent intentShareFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
            "My Subject");//Only used if user selects email client

    intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
            "Extra text");

    if (isReportInPDF())
        intentShareFile.setType("application/pdf");
    else
        intentShareFile.setType("application/vnd.ms-excel");

    intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + url));

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentShareFile, "Share File"));
```

Comment: There is no requirement for an app to support both `EXTRA_TEXT` and `EXTRA_STREAM` in the same `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`, so what you are describing fits how `ACTION_SEND` is documented. Note that `file:` `Uri` values are banned on Android 7.0+; you should be getting a `FileUriExposedException`. Please use `FileProvider` to publish your stream to the other app.

Comment: So Bottomline is I can't use both. And thanks for the note on FileProvider, I will look in the same.

Comment: "So Bottomline is I can't use both" -- I would phrase it as "you cannot rely on both". If you supply both extras, it is up to the consuming app to decide what to do with them, and not all apps will use both, or use them in ways that match your expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you supply both extras, it is up to the consuming app to decide
>   what to do with them and not all apps will use both.

As Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58448422/sending-document-and-text-both-in-whatsapp#comment103238124_58448422) comment.